# How to make Tile Images Smaller WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have an icon for my "Tiles" but the image I am using is white and the text for the application is white so that does not look good.

I look at the local scout titles or the "xbox" tiles and the icon is only in the middle and does not stretch the whole tile like my image does.

I tried to change the size of the image I am using but it always just stretches it.

How can I achieve what the "xbox" tile has?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows Phone 8, your tile must be 336 × 336 pixels. So create a picture with that size, put your icon in the picture at the desired size, then fill the gap between the icon and the border using the transparent color. This way, your picture won't be stretched.